# In tensorflow 2.0 how can I set model.fit labels with range like 1000~1100?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have [10,20,10,30] x data
and I want to set [12~14, 17~19, 12~12.5, 30~30.5] y data (label) not [13,18,12,30]
can I set label with range?

Comment: What you described can be achieved using a custom loss function. Let me know if you want me to write a simple example for you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need? For example do you need multi-label classification? Where a single sample has multiple labels?

Comment: @ShanqingCai Yes please thanks.

Comment: @thushv89 many and multiple labels(with a single sample) like [500~600, 700~800, 300~500, 1000~1200] 1000~1200 means 1000,1001,1002,1003, ... , 1199, 1200